# Changed from WoW's Starteredition to full

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have have had WoW's starter edition and I would like to upgrade but I'm completely lost. I plan on buying from Gamestop -- Should I buy their battle chest and slowly get expansions or is there and another way? Will it change how I play in WoW starter. Also does WoW need a monthly payment. Then should I just buy the 60 day card. Please explain to me like I was a 5 year old. I just realy want it to be the same I was playing in WoW starter. What happens when (if you have to) your subscription runs out. Does it just terminate?

Comment: Try reading their FAQ first, it outlines all your questions for new customers. http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/world-of-warcraft-starter-edition-account-faq http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/subscription-options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They won't delete your characters -_- after you lose your starter edition when your days expire your account gets freezed and you can't log in until you pay again.

You can buy battlechest if it is cheaper in your region...but you activate one by one as you play.I would buy one by one since old expansions get cheaper and cheaper with every expansion they release,and if you get bored in middle you can quit without spending money on all expansions.

1. You play until lvl  25 (Free)
2. Use WoW trial 10 day (should be on Battlenet page)
3. Buy WoW original (you get 30 days with it)
4. Buy 60 days key to get lvl 60 (if not already)
5. Use Burning crusade 10 day trial (should be on Battlenet page)
6. Buy Burning Crusade + 60 days
7. Use WoTLK 10 day trial (should be on Battlenet page)
8. Buy WoTLK + 60 days
9. Cataclysm 10 day trial (should be on Battlenet page)
10. Cataclysm + 60 days ...

Use your 10 day trials  when you reach max level,before that use 60 day keys as needed.

Comment: Buying the Battlechest should be cheaper since it contains WoW and BC. And it has also 30 Days free gametime.

Comment: It depends on price where he buys,where I am it isn't cheaper,30 days are included with WoW original,and he might not want to play BC.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I plan to follow your plan but I will buy  the battle chest.

Comment: Doesn't WoW upgrade all accounts to TBC for free?

Comment: FYI, All WoW accounts get the Burning Crusade for free now, so if you can find a copy of the original WoW only for cheaper than the battle chest, that is probably the better deal: http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/2545148